# How to post json data in Adobe AEM 6.2 using JAX-RS and Jersey

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, aem

I try to create a JSON API for my AEM apps. When I post the data as JSON to the service it always throw 415 error : Unsupported Media Type. Here is what I've done :

JSON data :

```
{ "fullName" : "myname"}
```

Java POJO class

```
public class FormDataBean {
    private String fullName;

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

Services class

```
@Component(metatype = false)
@Service({JsonAPI.class})
@Path("/postdata")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class JsonAPI
{
    @POST
    @Path("/form")
    public String getFormData(FormDataBean jsonData)
    {
        return formData.getFullName();
    }
}
```

List of dependencies :

- jackson-annotations-2.8.6.jar
- jackson-core-2.8.6.jar
- jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar
- jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.6.jar
- jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.6.jar
- jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.6.jar
- jersey-all-2.22.2.jar
- publisher-5.3.1.jar

I have searched around and some topic said that i need to register JacksonJsonProvider with ResourceConfig but how can I do it in AEM? My current workaround is sending the JSON as a String and map it to POJO using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` in my methods.

Answer (score 0):

Unsupported Media Type is the response JAX-RS provides when the list of available "@Produces" types does not match any values provided in the "accept" headers of the request.

You will need to add an http accept header to the client request.  The accept header must contain "application/json" in the list of acceptable response types.

For example, using curl would have to add -H "Accept:  application/json" to the curl command to add the accept header.  If your client can accept multiple response types, then the accept header can be a comma separated list of values.

Comment: It seem like that jersey does not auto register jackson-jaxrs-json-provider, after change to gson provier, it can map my json to java object. I try to manual register jackson provider with ResourceConfig class but I still doesn't work.